# Karate driver synchronization challeges

Tags: karate

Karate driven execution fails once in a while for certain elements where I use xpath. (Every three runs; one or two times it works.)

I tried the following code,

- `waitUntil("document.readyState == 'complete'")`
- `click("xpath")`  This line fails once in a while.

The xpath is consistently working on my existing Java [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) code.

Can another synchronization method be applied?

Comment: Only literal "xpath" or is it related to [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve the problem:

```
* waitFor('xpath').click()
```

Please read this part of the documentation carefully: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-core#wait-api

Also I have found `"document.readyState == 'complete'"` to be unreliable. Instead try `waitForUrl('partial/url')`.

Comment: Thanks,  it worked. The documentation is also really helpful. I had issues with iframes/nested frames and going through the documentation.